# .append keeps appending even though if statement is false

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not sure why, but when clicking my button, my code keeps appending even though it appears the if statement is false after the first append?

In line 9, I am checking to see if any .tab class has an attr that does not equal my variable sysId. No matter what I do, it keeps appending. I want it to only append once IF a .tab doesn't have an attribute of data-sysid= sysid already in place.

```
var recordHtml = '<div class="tab-content-record" data-sysid="">This is a record opened 
from the list.</div>';

// Open Record Tab
$(".tab-content-list-button").click(function () {
  var sysId = $(this).data('sysid');
  var title = $(this).data('title');
  var tabHtml = '<div class="tab record" data-sysid="' + sysId + '"><div class="tab-title">' + title + '</div><div class="close-tab">X</div></div>';

  if ($('.tab').attr('data-sysid') != sysId) {
    $(".tab-list").append(tabHtml);
  }

  //$(".tab-list").append(tabHtml);

})
```

Here is my fiddle that shows it working with the HTML & CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/fju60bca/1/

Comment: can you log out `$('.tab').attr('data-sysid')` and `sysId`?

Comment: Hmm, the  $('.tab').attr('data-sysid') is undefined. So I'll start there, I didn't even think of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many tab elements on the page, so the following statement won't return the attribute you are looking for:

```
$('.tab').attr('data-sysid')
```

You need to check each tab element to see if the one you are looking for exists:

```
let buttonExists = false; 

$("div.tab").each(function(index, tabElem) 
{
    if ($(tabElem).data('sysid') === sysId)
        buttonExists = true; 
});
  

if (!buttonExists) {
    $(".tab-list").append(tabHtml);
}
```

Comment: Boom, I was so close after reading tbjgoldens comment. I did do a for reach through them, but I was still missing something which was actually tracking the true/false if it was found or not then triggering the actual append off of that. Thank you!